# Start an activity in firebase facebook authentication code

Tags: android, facebook, firebase

Why i can't startActivity in the facebook authentification code ?

1.The code is running well except that after the login i want to start an activity ,mean it should be somewhere to put the startActivity methode

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private static final String TAG = "Login";
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };


    // Initialize Facebook Login button
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            //startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
            // ...
        }

    });

    // ...
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

}

// ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    //showProgressDialog
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    //hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END auth_with_facebook]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your `AuthStateListener` where currently you have:

```
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            // you can also add anything else that should happen when user
            // has successfully signed in
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
```

As the comment states, when `user != null` the user is signed in, so that's where you can start your Activity or whatever you want to do.

When the user is successfully signed into Firebase Auth via Facebook (or any other logins you add) the `onAuthStateChanged` method will be called.